# NSURLConnection receives 'False' on file download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to download a file from a server to an iphone like this

```
NSURL *newURL0 = [NSURL URLWithString: url]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *req0 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:newURL0];
NSURLConnection conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req0 delegate:self];
```

and then

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSURL *docDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:
                            NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

    NSURL *filePath = [docDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:temp];

    [webData writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES];
    [webData release];

    connection = nil ; 

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getDataSucceeded:)]) {

        NSLog(@"Log: %@", @"yes");
        [delegate getDataSucceeded:self.list];
    }
}
```

This always worked perfectly, but recently I have noticed that it does not work anymore.  No changes were made to any files relevant to this function, it just kind of stopped working.  when I use the same url in a web browser the file downloads fine, but in my app when I request the file it just returns 5 bytes, the word 'False' which I also found strange because the server does not return the word False, if there is an issue it returns a error message.  The server side code is written in Visual Basic.

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`False` is a keyword in Visual Basic, it is not a keyword in Objective-C.  There's also no reason for that to appear as text in a response like that.  It's almost certainly being generated server-side.

Use an HTTP proxy such as Charles to see what requests are made by your web browser and by your application.  There will be a difference between them that is causing the server to respond in a different way.  Use a tool like cURL to make requests manually to determine which of the differences is the cause.  Alternatively, check the commit log for your server-side code for recent changes that could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed the following call back function in which you need to append the chunck of data in a single NSData object :
in my case _responseText is a NSData object

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [_responseText appendData:data];
}
```

Hope this will help you out